# Prevent Windows Error Reporting (DW20.exe) window for a particular process

Tags: windows, error-reporting, user-interaction

I have an automated build system set up on a Windows box, but one of the compiling tools randomly fail to work. The whole system works as a service, so it has no interaction with users. I detect the failure by looking at the `DW20.exe` process. The failed process waits for a user to click a button, so it stops the whole build system.

Can I prevent Windows Error Reporting from waiting for user actions for a particular process (or a particular Windows user)?

The box has Windows Server 2008 R2 installed, and the process is Intel Fortran compiler (ifort.exe).

Answer (score 1):

There are some relevant options in [WER Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638%28VS.85%29.aspx), such as `DefaultConsent`, `DontShowUI` or (as a last resort) `ExcludedApplications`.